# Appearace of an extra character in command line after running a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run some diskpart commands from a text file and save its output to another text file.This is written in my batch file which i want to do it.

```
DISKPART /S E:\CMD.TXT > E:\OUT.TXT
PAUSE
```

and when I run it (even as administrator) it doesn't work well and this is written in the black screen of CMD:

```
DISKPART /S E:\CMD.TXT  1>E:\OUT.TXT
PAUSE
```

That extra 1 makes it not work correctly. whats that? and how can I solve it dear friends?

Comment: seems good to me. `>` is just an abbreviation for `1>`, so no reason to worry. What do you mean with `doesn't work well`? What does it, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: We need to see the error (screenshot it) and it would help if you posted the contents of cmd.txt.  If you run the above without the redirection to Out.txt, does it complete as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows supports a number of "standard devices"

> 0 is standard input (stdin) - normally assigned to the keyboard.
>   1 is standard output (stdout) - normally assigned to console
>   2 is standard error (stderr) - normally assigned to console

So, you could write a program which accepts input from stdin and writes results to stdout and errors to stderr (not all programs use stderr)

When you redirect input or output using redirectors (`<` and `>`) you can assign the input to a file if you wish, or direct output or errors likewise to a file.

The separate redirection of stdout and stderr is new to the NT-series of Windows (2K,XP,Vista,7,8,10) and `>` is assumed to mean `stdout gets redirected`. To redirect stdout **explicitly** you need to use `1>`. To redirect stderr **explicitly** you need to use `2>`.

Windows inserts the `1` to indicate that `stdout` is being redirected, but not `stderr`.

So - there's nothing amiss with what is being reported.

What is your command intended to do? COuld it be that windows is objecting to an attempt to create a file on `E:` when `E:` is the subject of a `diskpart` operation?

Comment: Thanks Magoo. the problem was somethings else. the original input txt file was named "Dastoorha" (means Commands in Persian). I changed the name to CMD and problem solved thanks..